# plotting: 4D in 2D

Tags: graphing-functions

I usually use the following trick to show a 3D plot (where I have $f(a,b)$ and I want to show the values of $f$ versus different values of $a$ and $b$) in a 2D plot:

[image: PLEASE SEEEEEEEEE THE IMAGE]

I'm wondering what are some ideas for showing a 4D graph in a 2D plot where I have $f(a,b,c)$ and I want to show the values of $f$ versus different values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

**You can simply assume: $a$ and $b$ are continuous and $c$ is discrete**

---

I was not sure which forum is appropriate to ask this general question about visualization but I'm hoping to find some advice from math perspective here.

Comment: Appreciate if someone with a high rank, make my attached image visible. Thanks @Arthur for his quick edit.

Comment: Here be dragons.